# How to map from one json to another json

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using Java and Spring Boot technology in my project. So I will get the request data from the database as an entity class. Then I want to give the response in a different JSON format, which I have given below.

I can create the POJO class for response json, and using the getter and setter methods, I can achieve this, but could you please tell me any other good ways to achieve this? I can use objectMapper, but some parameter (key) names are different, and it will not set values for the "additionalInfo" json object.

Could you please help me find some solutions to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!**

```
 Request:
    --------
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Iswarya Elango",
      "email": "abc@gmail.com",
      "age": "25",
      "gender": "female",
      "nationality": "xyz",
      "language": "English",
      "academyDetails": [
        {
          "subject": "English",
          "mark": "99"
        },
        {
          "subject": "Maths",
          "mark": "100"
        }
      ]
    }
    
    Expected Response:
    ------------------
    {
      "id": "1",
      "fullName": "Iswarya Elango",
      "email": "abc@gmail.com",
      "additionalInfo": [
        {
          "age": "25",
          "gender": "female",
          "nationality": "xyz",
          "language": "English",
          
        }
      ],
      "academy": [
        {
          "score": "99"
        },
        {
          "score": "100"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map-struct. It can map one field to another from source to target object. avoids a lot of boiler plate code. works well with spring and you can inject them as normal beans. If you are good with generics you can play with it in n number of ways. You can read about it here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mapstruct/index.htm
It is a very versatile mapping lib.

```
@Component
public interface MyMapper<T extends Entity, K extends Pojo> {


  K toPojo(T entity);

  T toEntity(K dto);

}

Impl:

@Component
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {AnotherMapper.class})
public abstract class EmployeeMapper implements MyMapper<EmployeeEntity, EmployeePojo> {

  @Autowired
  protected SomeLookupService someLookupService;


  @Mapping(source = "dto.fullname", target = "name")
  public abstract EmployeeEntity toEntity(EmployeePojo dto);


  @Mapping(source = "entity.name", target = "fullname")
  @Mapping(source = "entity", target = "additionalInfo", qualifiedByName = "additionalInfo")
  public abstract EmployeePojo toPojo(EmployeeEntity entity);

  @Named("additionalInfo")
  protected String populateAdditionalInfo(Entity entity) {

    // your own logic to populate AdditionalInfo.java
  }
}

Note:
 
EmployeeEntity extends Entity
EmployeePojo extends Pojo
someLookupService -> if you wanna inject some other component to do complex operations during mapping and modify content, for example populating some aggregations etc. Depends on how you would like to use.
AnotherMapper.class -> a similar mapper if you have nested fields which are complex types.
```

You can inject this mapper straight into your service code.

Comment: Could you please share any example code for it? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may try library *Josson* to transform the JSON.

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"id\": \"1\"," +
    "  \"name\": \"Iswarya Elango\"," +
    "  \"email\": \"abc@gmail.com\"," +
    "  \"age\": \"25\"," +
    "  \"gender\": \"female\"," +
    "  \"nationality\": \"xyz\"," +
    "  \"language\": \"English\"," +
    "  \"academyDetails\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"subject\": \"English\"," +
    "      \"mark\": \"99\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "      \"subject\": \"Maths\"," +
    "      \"mark\": \"100\"" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "map(" +
    "    id," +
    "    fullName: name," +
    "    email," +
    "    additionalInfo: wrap(map(" +
    "        age, gender, nationality, language" +
    "    ))," +
    "    academy: academyDetails.map(score: mark)" +
    ")");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "id" : "1",
  "fullName" : "Iswarya Elango",
  "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
  "additionalInfo" : [ {
    "age" : "25",
    "gender" : "female",
    "nationality" : "xyz",
    "language" : "English"
  } ],
  "academy" : [ {
    "score" : "99"
  }, {
    "score" : "100"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way without adding any libraries? Or, Is it possible to map all values using objectMapper or Gson?